# Exclude read more in the_excerpt

Tags: theme-development, excerpt, read-more

I want to remove "read more" in the next code:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Is it possible to do in the PHP line directly or I need a filter in funtions.php? I am want to do one by one in PHP query not for all.

Comment: `the_excerpt()` doesn't output "read more" by default. If it's appearing then your theme would be adding it, and you'd need to remove the filter from functions.php. The specifics would depend on the theme. I suggest asking its author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked to author theme. It was by filter from functions.php